How to know when filevault decryption has finished
I have turned off FileVault I want to know when it has been completed, for the moment it has not ended because time machine backup is not possible.
I want to add that  I have turned off and on my macbook pro after backup has completed I now it is again disabled (and it has taken time -5min- to show login screen at boot) so I want to turn off my machine only when  everything is fine. So is there a way to check the progress?
should I reinstall macos (does it erase my data/apps?)

What version of macOS? What disk format?  If formatted APFS then diskutil apfs list in Terminal.
